# what is the equivalent method for .pack("H*")].pack("m0") of Ruby in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, base64

In Ruby, I use function `.pack("H*")].pack("m0")` to encode a hex message string to base64 string.

ex.

```rb
msg_hex = 8308862831031591345F010101020663602A06E300000000EF934E0C5B29E50E000000000000000000000310000000004F04010000010000
msg_hex.pack("H*")].pack("m0") => gwiGKDEDFZE0XwEBAQIGY2AqBuMAAAAA75NODFsp5Q4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAxAAAAAATwQBAAABAAA=
```

In Javascript, I am looking for an equivalent method to convert message to 64base message. Some answers tell useing `Buffer.from(msg_hex).toString('base64')`, but the result is different.

```js
const msg_hex = 8308862831031591345F010101020663602A06E300000000EF934E0C5B29E50E000000000000000000000310000000004F04010000010000
Buffer.from(msg_hex).toString('base64') // => ODMwODg2MjgzMTAzMTU5MTM0NUYwMTAxMDEwMjA2NjM2MDJBMDZFMzAwMDAwMDAwRUY5MzRFMEM1QjI5RTUwRTAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMzEwMDAwMDAwMDA0RjA0MDAwMDAwMDEwMDAw
```

what is the equivalent method for `.pack("H*")].pack("m0")` of Ruby in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You was nearly there with what you supplied.

You just forgot to tell `Buffer.from` what you was supplying, as default if you send a string it's just going to store it as a string.  But what you wanted was to decode the source as hex and then store as binary.

So doing ->

```
Buffer.from(msg_hex, 'hex').toString('base64')
```

IOW: you just missed the second parameter `hex`..